# How to launch a winstore app from within another winstore app

Tags: javascript, winjs

I am currently building a win-store app for a client, and I can't seem to figure out how to link to another app from within my current app.

I have seen plenty of documentation on how to open the default application from a URI or file type but nothing on opening a specific app.

Currently I am able to open my app with the function below, after adding a protocol to the declarations in my package.appxmanifest, but this isn't the preferred solution since this will not cause the app to open in full screen.

```
function openApp() {

    var options = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions();
    options.preferredApplicationPackageFamilyName = "packageFamilyName";
    options.preferredApplicationDisplayName = "App Display Name";

    var uri = new Windows.Foundation.Uri("linktomyapphere:");


    Windows.System.Launcher.launchUriAsync(uri).then(
        function (e) {},
        function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is definitely URL activation (aka protocol activation). If you own the other app, you register a protocol for it - something like `myapp://`. That is done in the manifest. Then you follow the instructions on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452686.aspx) to activate that from your app. You can even pass URL parameters so you can pass some state in during activation.